# pyspark streaming read two streams sequential. after getting data from the first stream run the second

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

i have a use case where i have a Stream_1 and Stream_2. Stream_1 only runs for about 5 seconds i want to get the some data to use (filter) it with Stream_2. stream_2 keep running for the whole process. how can i do that using pyspark structure streaming.

```
# The first Stream
stream_1= spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker01:29092") \
  .option("subscribe", "topic_1") \
  .load()

#filtering and take 2 values, value X,Y

query1 = stream_1 \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()


# The second Stream
stream_2= spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker01:29092") \
  .option("subscribe", "topic_2") \
  .load()

# Filtering and use value X,Y from the stream_1

query2 = stream_2 \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()
```

Comment: You can join two streams

Comment: yes but i dont want to join them, i only want to take some data from the first one. to let the process be faster

Comment: .processAllAvailable() can do it ??
because i am not using the first stream after the 5 first seconds

Comment: @s.polam we know that stream_1 start first and just for 5 seconds and than after (about 3 to 5 min) start stream_2.
((the stream_1 is like reading from csv it only reads stream one time))

Comment: isnt there another way to do it than foreachbatch because i already implement my logic. just want to read the 2 values . the 2 values from the first stream are static values they dont change until the process ends. you can imagine it as 2 variable that are read from a stream

Comment: @s.polam ok, and read only the first batch and if its there than start the second stream_2 ?

Comment: @s.polam can you please show me in my code above how to do this. i will be very thankful